# Enable angular routes with asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-core

i'm trying to build a web app with `asp.net core` for back-end side and `angular 1.5.x` for front-end side. the problem is haw to enable angular routes to be analyzed by the server. i added these lines of code to the `startup.cs` and evry thing works fine:

```
 DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions();
            options.DefaultFileNames.Clear();
            options.DefaultFileNames.Add("Index.html");
            app.Use(async (context, next) =>
            {
                await next();

                if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 && !Path.HasExtension(context.Request.Path.Value))
                {
                    context.Request.Path = "/Index.html";
                    await next();
                }
            })
            .UseCors("AllowAll")
            .UseDefaultFiles(options)
            .UseStaticFiles()
            .UseIdentity()
            .UseMvc();
```

but i looks like it's not a good practice, and this problem should be solved in the `appsettings.json`. any ideas ?

Comment: Use JavaScriptServices: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices they add both server-sided nodejs (including angular) rendering as well as enables a default route which will route first-time calls to the index/home/whatever page where the SPA is embedded. All conclusive calls are handled by the angular router

Comment: @Tseng haw to do it with the appsettings.json file ?

Comment: Why? It's very unlikely you gonna change the route/controller on the run. Angular SPAs just need a single entry point (that's where the name comes from **Single** Page Application)

Comment: @Tseng haw to told the server to use the entry point ?  as if you say evrything will work automatically !

Comment: i added Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices , Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices and Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices packages, it works fine but   i have an exception adding the Mvc in startup.cs

Comment: I took your solution and it worked like a charm but it has one downside that all 404 links will be redirected to index even if it is actually a 404 link, i think this could be resolved someway will dig more on it.
@Tseng Javascriptservices only work if you use MVC, if you only use API then this library will not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer (mostly) is in the UseMVC options...
you should implement server-side routes as shown

```
    app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute("spa-fallback", new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

look at this [link](http://blog.nbellocam.me/2016/03/21/routing-angular-2-asp-net-core/)

Comment: I said (mostly) because I never tested it but I think it's a reasonable answer...